# Do I need to enable OpenMP on a project that loads a shared object that has been compiled with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, openmp

I'm loading a shared shared object file on Linux that utilizes OpenMP. The shared object is compiled with shared object enabled. Do I need to compile the project that loads the shared object also with omp?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile sources without OpenMP features with the OpenMP compiler options, but at the end you need to link with the libraries needed by OpenMP. So what is important is to specify the appropriate option in the link command (or to explicitly pick the needed libraries).